# Setting autoincrement other than default: Laravel is not aware of the change

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote a migration for a table and I need the first item of the table to be fixed for default cases (i.e. id=1 is unknown).

Here's the code:

```
 Schema::create('technicians', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname')->nullable();
            $table->integer('str_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('str_id')->references('id')->on('services');
        });

        \DB::statement('ALTER TABLE technicians AUTO_INCREMENT = 2;');
```

However, when Laravel tries to create new entries it tries to create entries using the id and using 1 to begin with. How do I tell Laravel Eloquent to start from 2? As you can see I already tried something but it seems like Eloquent tries to add the id on its own.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `technicians` (`id`, `name`, `str_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 'JOHN DOE', 3, 2019-03-11 13:50:00, 2019-03-11 13:50:00))

EDIT: This is the entry in the DB

```
public function run()
    {
        $default = new Technician;
        $default->id = 1;
        $default->name = "DESCONOCIDO";
        $default->str_id = 1;
        $default->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the table has been created, unless I have misunderstood, why not just fill the first entry so it increments past 1?

For example, create a DB seed to insert data into the table for whatever record you need.

[Laravel DB Seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding)

Run `php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder`

Then in the seed file:

```
public function run()
    {
        DB::table('technicians')->insert([
            'name' => "John",
            'surname' => "Doe",
            'str_id' => 3,
            etc...
        ]);
    }
```

It looks like you are trying to insert a record in the DB where one already exists for the ID of 1. Check your DB.

Comment: I added an entry but Eloquent doesn't notice it. I'll edit to show you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set autoincrement start with this code

```
$table->increments('id')->start_from($yourStartValue);
```

add start_from and use your value for start

Comment: Really? I can't find that in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, you can try it.